# Any suggestion for Django-FloppyFroms client side validation

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, semantic-ui

Here are few links for Django FloppyForms. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-floppyforms

I would like to use frontend/client side validation for my froms. I am using Django and semantic UI for my project.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do client side validation, you need to use Javascript in the browser. It is you django code which provides the form and attributes to your html, but you still need client side code in order to perform client side validation. This is completely decoupled from you server side.

You are using Semantic UI, which has built-in form validation. See [here](https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html) for more detailed information on how to use it.